# How to create cross (right top) animation using css?

Tags: css, animation

I'm trying to create cross side animation using CSS3. Since i'm not expert that's why I don't have idea how can I do it. I have searched about it and find tutorial of key frame. I done left right top and bottom animation using below code.

```
   div {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: red;
        position: relative;
        -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        animation-name: example;
        animation-duration: 4s;
    }

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    0%   {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
    25%  {background-color:yellow; left:200px; top:0px;}
    50%  {background-color:blue; left:200px; top:200px;}
    75%  {background-color:green; left:0px; top:200px;}
    100% {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example {
    0%   {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
    25%  {background-color:yellow; left:200px; top:0px;}
    50%  {background-color:blue; left:200px; top:200px;}
    75%  {background-color:green; left:0px; top:200px;}
    100% {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
}
```

But I need cross animation. Actually I want to animate the broadcast signals using CSS3. I'm adding the reference [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZaXq.png) for further understanding. I would like to appreciate it. I know this is a stupid question but I really need your guideline.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```css
div {
  top: 200px
  left: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    0%   {background-color:red; left:0px; top:200px;}
    25%  {background-color:yellow; left:50px; top:150px;}
    50%  {background-color:blue; left:100px; top:100px;}
    75%  {background-color:green; left:150px; top:50px;}
    100% {background-color:red; left:200px; top:0px;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example {
    0%   {background-color:red; left:0px; top:200px;}
    25%  {background-color:yellow; left:50px; top:150px;}
    50%  {background-color:blue; left:100px; top:100px;}
    75%  {background-color:green; left:150px; top:50px;}
    100% {background-color:red; left:200px; top:0px;}
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```